# Convert hex integer into form "\x" (c++ - memory)

Tags: c++, memory

```
DWORD FindPattern(DWORD base, DWORD size, char *pattern, char *mask)
{
    // Get length for our mask, this will allow us to loop through our array
    DWORD patternLength = (DWORD)strlen(mask);

    for (DWORD i = 0; i < size - patternLength; i++)
    {
        bool found = true;
        for (DWORD j = 0; j < patternLength; j++)
        {
            // If we have a ? in our mask then we have true by default, 
            // or if the bytes match then we keep searching until finding it or not
            found &= mask[j] == '?' || pattern[j] == *(char*)(base + i + j);
        }

        // Found = true, our entire pattern was found
        // Return the memory addy so we can write to it
        if (found)
        {
            return base + i;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Above is my FindPattern function that I use to find bytes in a given section of memory, here's how I call the function:

```
DWORD PATTERN = FindPattern(0xC0000000, 0x20000,"\x1F\x37\x66\xE3", "xxxx");
PrintStringBottomCentre("%02x", PATTERN);
```

Now, say I had an integer for example: 0xDEADBEEF
I want to convert this into a char pointer like: "\xDE\xAD\xBE\xEF", this is so that I can put it into my FindPattern function. How would I do this?

Comment: The `\x` form is a string _literal_ form in your code. It doesn't exist in memory. Same as `0xDEADBEEF` in fact; the `0x` is just for the compiler.

Comment: So you're saying I don't need the \x?

Comment: Indeed, you create the pattern at runtime and then there's no compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be careful here. On many architectures including x86, `int`s are stored using [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), meaning that the int `0xDEADBEEF` is stored in memory in this order: `EF BE AD DE`. But the char array is stored in the order `DE AD BE EF`.

So the question is, are you trying to find an int `0xDEADBEEF` stored in memory, or do you actually want the sequence of bytes `DE AD BE EF`?

If you want the int, don't use a char* array at all. Pass in your pattern and mask as DWORDs, and you can simplify that function a lot.

If you want to find the sequence of bytes, then don't store it as an int in the first place. Just get the input as a char array and pass it directly in as your pattern.

---

Edit: you can try something like this, which I think will give you what you want:

```
int a = 0xDEADBEEF;
char pattern[4];
pattern[0] = (a >> 24) & 0xFF;
pattern[1] = (a >> 16) & 0xFF;
pattern[2] = (a >> 8) & 0xFF;
pattern[3] = a & 0xFF;
```

Comment: I'm using a function that has to return an int, then the bytes that get returned is what is to be the pattern

Comment: @MCDOOGLEye ok I think I get what you're looking for. see my edit

Comment: Ok, this is my code and the output: https://gyazo.com/04139c73b075e3bddc502adf256dd6b0 I don't want the FFFFFF at the start of the value.

Edit: I put int instead of char and it does what I want it to, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `\` character in C/C++ is an escape character, so anything that follows it is translated to the escape character you want, hex conversion (`\x`) in your string. In order to avoid that, add another `\` before it so it will be considered as a normal character.

Ex.) `\\xDE\\xAD\\xBE\\xEF`

Comment: In the pattern, would I even need to use the "\x"?

Comment: It depends on what you need in processing. In your sample function call, `DWORD PATTERN = FindPattern(0xC0000000, 0x20000,"\x1F\x37\x66\xE3", "xxxx");`, the `\x` is included in the function argument so I assumed you need it.